# (co)chain homotopy of dg algebras ($A_{\infty}$ algebras) and other notion of homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, a-infinity-algebras

In this question I will work over a field of char. $0$. Let $f,g\: : \: A\to B$ be dg algebras morphism between two cochain (commutative) dg algebras $A,B$ (assume positively graded). Let $h$ be a cochain homotopy between f and g, i.e. a linear map $h\: : \: A^{*}\to B^{*-1}$ such that $dh+hd=f-g$. This notion of homotopy seems to be not the correct one for dg algebras (see for example [Do chain homotopic maps between dg-algebras induce “same” maps on dg-modules?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265059/do-chain-homotopic-maps-between-dg-algebras-induce-same-maps-on-dg-modules)). Let $\Lambda(t)$ be the dg algebra of polynomial forms on the interval $[0,1]$. The ''correct'' notion of homotopy between $f$ and $g$ seems to be: $f$ and $g$ are homotopic iff there exist a dg algebra morphism $H\: : \: A\to B\otimes \Lambda(t)$ such that
$$
H(a,0)=f(a),\quad H(a,1)=g(a).
$$
It is possible to turn $H$ in a cochain homotopy by define $h:=\int_{0}^{1}H$ such that: if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic via $H$ they are chain homotopic via $h$. Here my questions:

1) It seems to me that there should be an obstruction to produce an homotopy $H$ from a chain homotopy $h$ (see for example the მამუკაჯიბლაძე's comment in [Do chain homotopic maps between dg-algebras induce “same” maps on dg-modules?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265059/do-chain-homotopic-maps-between-dg-algebras-induce-same-maps-on-dg-modules)). Is there a way to "measure" this obstruction?

2) Under which conditions on $A$ and $B$ does this obstruction vanishes?($A $ cofibrant? $A$, $B$ minimal algebras?)

3) The same discussion above works as well in the context of $A_{\infty}$ algebras. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are $A_{\infty}$ algebras. A notion of homotopy between $A_{\infty}$ algebra maps $f_{\bullet}, g_{\bullet}\: : \: A\to B$ may be the following: there exist an $A_{\infty}$ algebra map $H_{\bullet}\: :\: A\to B\otimes\Lambda(t)$ such that
$$
H_{\bullet}(a,0)=f_{\bullet}(a),\quad H_{\bullet}(a,1)=g_{\bullet}(a).
$$
Similarly we can define the notion of cochain homotopy between $A_{\infty}$ algebra maps. My question is: what will be the translation of question 1),2) in terms of $A_{\infty}$ ($C_{\infty}$) algebras?

4)Here a non trivial example. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401007)) about the homotopy transfer theorem an explicit chain homotopy between $A_{\infty}$ algebra maps is constructed. Let $A$ be a dg algebra and H(A) its cohomology. Consider a (cochain) quasi isomorphism $i\: : \: H(A)\to A$, a cochain map $p\: : \: A\to H(A) $ such that $pi=Id$. Assume that there exists a cochain homotopy between $ip$ and the identity maps on $A$. Then there exist

a) an $A_{\infty}$ structure on $H(A)$,

b) quasi isomorphism (of $A_{\infty}$ algebras) $g_{\bullet}$, $f_{\bullet}$ such that $f_{1}=p$ and $g_{1}=i$.

c) a "cochain homotopy*" $h_{\bullet}$ between $(g_{\bullet} \circ f_{\bullet})$ and the identity on $A$.

Here the question: Is it possible to turn $h_{\bullet}$ into $H_{\bullet}$ here? what will be the condition on $A$?

EDIT: As pointed out by Gabriel, the definition in Markl's paper is more elaborated. For $n>1$, $h_{n}$ is not merely a cochain map betwen $(f\circ g)_{n}$ and $0$.

Comment: In (3), should it be $B\otimes \Lambda(t)$?

Comment: You've explicitly said you're working in characteristic zero, so there's no _problem_ with your definition of homotopy which uses polynomial forms, but this is going to clash with just about any definition you find in the literature. Since $A_\infty$ works perfectly well in any characteristic and even over the integers, any reasonable reference will give a definition of $A_\infty$ homotopy which works in any characteristic and over the integers. Your definition using polynomial forms, which involves derivatives of polynomials and thus division by arbitrarily large integers, does not.

Comment: So any answer to question 4 will have to deal with the fact that your definition of $A_\infty$ homotopy is non-standard. Setting that aside, I think you've misunderstood your reference. In Problem 2-(iv) and Theorem 5 of the reference, the construction is given of an "$A_\infty$ homotopy $\mathbf{H}$" (what I would characterize as the correct definition, not the same as your definition), explicitly NOT just a cochain homotopy $h$. The definition used by Markl of an $A_\infty$ homotopy is item (6) in Section 2 (Conventions).

Comment: @David White, yes! Now is fixed.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole, Yes I see, $h_{2}$ is something more than a cochain homotopy!  Thanks, so the "polynomial definition" and the Markl's one are equivalent over a field of charachteristic 0, but the "polynomial definition" is not well defined over a field of charachteristic $p$ for example. Is it then possible to construct $H_{\bullet}$ from $h_{\bullet}$ explicitly?

Comment: When you say  "Is it then possible," what does "then" mean? Markl's construction of (his) $H_*$ from $h_*$, which is explicit, works over any unital commutative ring. The polynomial definition, as you say, is not well-behaved in characteristic $p$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: Assume that we are working on a filed of char. zero. Is it possible to write down explicit a "polynomial Homotopy" starting from the formula of Markl?

Comment: Yes. This should be more or less standard and should follow abstractly from an equivalence from the "noncommutative interval" to the "polynomial interval" that is only valid in characteristic zero; alternatively you could write down a differential equation to interpolate between them which will then be formally solvable by induction order by order in your polynomial variable $t$.

Comment: Since we are in caracteristic zero, do you know if such a $h_{\bullet}$ (Markl's one) exists if $A$ is a  $C_{\infty}$ algebra? Maybe the same formulas for $h_{\bullet}$ gived in the paper works...

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Hi, sorry to revive such an old thread/comment. I've recently come across this problem of translating Markl's definition of an $A_{\infty}$ homotopy to the "Sullivan definition" defined via an $A_{\infty}$ map from $ A \rightarrow B \otimes \Omega$. Do you have a reference or something for how this can be done? You mentioned a method in your comment, but is it written out somewhere? Thank you! I would greatly appreciate any help you can give on this..

Comment: @Elliot I don't have a reference, sorry.